# Not getting an output for my code

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

My code for converting Roman Numerals to their Decimal Form seems to be correct, but for some reason I cannot figure out how to get any sort of output. I want to say at the end `"The Roman Number" + roman numeral + "is" + decimal number`. How, and where would I put that?

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
    public class RomantoInteger {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter an Roman numeral with an equivalent between 0 and 3999:");
    }

    public class Roman {

    private final char[] romanNumerals = { 'M', 'D', 'C', 'L', 'X', 'V', 'I' };
    private final int[] romanEquivalent = { 1000, 500, 100, 50, 10, 5, 1 };
    private final String romanNum;   
    private int decimalNum; 

    public Roman(String input) {
        romanNum = input.toUpperCase();
    }

    //public void checkRoman(){
    //  for(int x=romanNum.length()-1;x<romanNum.length(); x++){
    //      if(romanNum.charAt(x)=='M')
    //  }
    //}

    /*
     * Method to convert roman number to decimal
     */
    public int convertToDecimal() {
        int sum[];                                     //Create a integer array
        sum = new int[romanNum.length()];               //set the size of sum array to the length of romanNum

        for (int y = 0; y < romanNum.length(); y++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < romanNumerals.length; i++) {
                if ((romanNum.charAt(y) == romanNumerals[i])       
                        && (romanNum.length() > 1)) {             //and if length of romanNum is greater than 1
                    sum[y] = romanEquivalent[i];                       //store the value of the matching romanNumeral to an indexed variable of array sum
                }
                if ((romanNum.charAt(y) == romanNumerals[i])           //if
                        && (romanNum.length() == 1)) {       //and if length of romanNum is just 1
                    System.out.println(romanEquivalent[i]);     //print out the value of the matching romanNumeral
                    break;                                       //terminate looping (for loop)
                }
            }
        }
        return add(sum);                                            //call method add
    }

    public int add(int[] sum) {
        int lastIndex = sum.length - 1;
        int decimalNum = sum[lastIndex];
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = lastIndex; count < sum.length - 1; count++) {
            if ((sum[i - 1] <= sum[i])) {                 
                decimalNum = decimalNum - sum[i - 1];
                --i;
            } else {
                decimalNum = decimalNum + sum[i - 1];
                --i;
            }
        }
        return decimalNum;
    }

}

}
```

Comment: The first problem I see is that your program isn't doing anything after asking for input. The class `Roman` is not instantiated anywhere.

Comment: I introduced a scanner, and i prompted a question asking for input, could you explain what you mean? I'm still confused.

Comment: The last line of your `main` function is the prompt asking the user for input. Once that line displays, nothing happens after, because there is no code after it. You need to instantiate your `Roman` class and call its methods.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a beginner with java, what is instantiating a class mean?

Comment: instantiating a class means something like this `Roman roman = new Roman(value);`.

Comment: I tried inserting it, it's giving me an error message that says: "non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context"

Comment: Class instantiation is one of the basics of object-oriented programming. Read up on it here: http://www.javaying.com/2006/10/class-instantiation.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well following concept that need to be clear

**Fact about final variable**

final variable SHOULD be initialize on the time of deceleration like

```
private final romanNum = "SomeRomanNumber";
```

OR

```
private final ronamNum = "";
```

So you solution is

```
import java.util.Scanner;


    public class RomantoInteger {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter an Roman numeral with an equivalent between 0 and 3999:");
        int value = input.nextInt();
        RomantoInteger rn = new RomantoInteger();
        Roman roman = rn.new Roman(""+value); //Roman is subclass of RomantoInteger and it is been called from static method so it should be call like this rn.new Roman(""+value);

        // Here you can call any function of Roman class
        }

        public class Roman {

        private final char[] romanNumerals = { 'M', 'D', 'C', 'L', 'X', 'V', 'I' };
        private final int[] romanEquivalent = { 1000, 500, 100, 50, 10, 5, 1 };
        private final String romanNum = "";   
        private int decimalNum; 

        public Roman(String input) {
            romanNum = input.toUpperCase();
        }

        //public void checkRoman(){
        //  for(int x=romanNum.length()-1;x<romanNum.length(); x++){
        //      if(romanNum.charAt(x)=='M')
        //  }
        //}

        /*
         * Method to convert roman number to decimal
         */
        public int convertToDecimal() {
            int sum[];                                     //Create a integer array
            sum = new int[romanNum.length()];               //set the size of sum array to the length of romanNum

            for (int y = 0; y < romanNum.length(); y++) {
                for (int i = 0; i < romanNumerals.length; i++) {
                    if ((romanNum.charAt(y) == romanNumerals[i])       
                            && (romanNum.length() > 1)) {             //and if length of romanNum is greater than 1
                        sum[y] = romanEquivalent[i];                       //store the value of the matching romanNumeral to an indexed variable of array sum
                    }
                    if ((romanNum.charAt(y) == romanNumerals[i])           //if
                            && (romanNum.length() == 1)) {       //and if length of romanNum is just 1
                        System.out.println(romanEquivalent[i]);     //print out the value of the matching romanNumeral
                        break;                                       //terminate looping (for loop)
                    }
                }
            }
            return add(sum);                                            //call method add
        }

        public int add(int[] sum) {
            int lastIndex = sum.length - 1;
            int decimalNum = sum[lastIndex];
            int count = 0;
            for (int i = lastIndex; count < sum.length - 1; count++) {
                if ((sum[i - 1] <= sum[i])) {                 
                    decimalNum = decimalNum - sum[i - 1];
                    --i;
                } else {
                    decimalNum = decimalNum + sum[i - 1];
                    --i;
                }
            }
            return decimalNum;
        }

    }

    }
```

Comment: I tried inserting it, it's giving me an error message that says: "non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context"

Comment: Answer is updated. Check it. If you get help from my answer then please mark it correct.